# Как мне загрузить картинку в папку img?

Tags: php

Почему я не могу загрузить картинку в папку img??? Где я допустил ошибку?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST'){

$input = $_POST['input'];

} else {

$input = $_GET['status'];

}

switch ($input){

case 'add_products':

      if(!empty($_FILES)){
          if($_FILES['image']['error'] == 0){

              $tmp_file = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
              $filename = $_FILES['image']['name'];

              move_uploaded_file($tmp_file, "img/". $filename);


                $col_id_name = "id";
                $row_id = $_POST['product_id'];
                $table_name = "bibliotek_books";

                $table_data;
                $table_data['title'] = $_POST['title'];
                $table_data['forfatter'] = $_POST['forfatter'];
                $table_data['isbn_nr'] = $_POST['isbn_nr'];
                $table_data['forlag'] = $_POST['forlag'];
                $table_data['antal_sider'] = $_POST['antal_sider'];
                $table_data['udgivelsesdato'] = $_POST['udgivelsesdato'];
                $table_data['mini_text'] = $_POST['mini_text'];
                $table_data['text'] = $_POST['text'];
                $table_data['billede'] = $_FILES['image']['name'];
                $categories = $_POST['category'];

                $insert_id = create($table_name, $table_data);

                foreach ($categories as $value){

                    create("bibliotek_books_cat", array("bibliotek_books_id"=>$insert_id, "bibliotek_category_id"=>$value));
                }

                header('Location: /Bibliotek/admin/index.php?page=products');


          }
          else{
              echo 'Image cannot upload, plz try again';
          }
      }

    break;

    default:

    echo "Handler fejl";
}
```

Comment: Автор, оформите вопрос правильно!

Comment: Я что только не пробывал не получаеться, название картинки выводит в базу данных а вот саму картинку не загружает в папку img где и как мне его правельно оформить?

Comment: Мне кажется вы формат упустили:

`move_uploaded_file($tmp_file, "img/". $filename . '.jpg');`

Comment: Всё также не загружаеться.